# Android - Changing Phone's Timezone

Tags: android, datetime

Is is possible to set the phone's timezone programmatically in android? I got this code

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();       
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
 System.out.println(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

but it does not change the phone's timezone. It only displays the timezone of America/Los Angeles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you are showing simply defines a Calendar instance with a specific format to be used in the app.
It is not possible to change the phone's timezone programmatically.

You could redirect the user to the appropriate settings:

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: It shows the phone's date/time(zone) settings to the user so he/she can manually change it. This is the closes you can get from within your app.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this only changes formatting, so you cannot expect it to change phone's time zone. And no, there are no APIs for changing time or timezone, this is reserved for system apps.